# Xcode cannot build IPA file

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, ipa

I am trying to build a file IPA by Xcode 6.1.1. But my Xcode say:

> "The password supplied for the account @"xxx" was rejected.Please make
>   sure that your password is correct in the Accounts preference pane"

What's happen to my Xcode? I have to update to 6.2, right?

Comment: I use an account: abcxyz@.com, and account: xxx is a different account.
I logged in both account.

Comment: Delete the account from **XCode -> Preferences**. And in Build Settings, Select Team to **None**

Answer (score 7):

It is because one of your account logged in have experiencing password changes.
You can remove that error by doing this;

Go to XCode->Preference->Accounts

Delete the account that causes a problem, or change the password to the correct one.